# sorting table containing dates in format dd.mm.yyyy using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, date

I have written the functionality for sorting as follows,

```
function sort_table(tbody, col, asc){
  var rows = tbody.rows, rlen = rows.length, arr = new Array(), i, j, cells,clen;
  // fill the array with values from the table
  for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
  cells = rows[i].cells;
  clen = cells.length;
  arr[i] = new Array();
      for(j = 0; j < clen; j++){
      arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
      }
  }
  // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
       return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
  });
 for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
     arr[i] = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
 }
 tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";
}
```

and the call as given below invokes the function

```
 sort_table(tb, 0, -1);
```

where

```
 tb = $($('th')[0]).parent().parent().parent().find('tbody')[0];
```

but my table consists of date values in columns which are of the format
dd.mm.yyyy

for example,
30.01.1993 can be one of the values in the tables cell.
the sorting code is not working for this particular format,otherwise its working fine.

How do i sort a column which consists of values in this particular format.

Comment: Are all of the fields in the date columns in that format?

Comment: I'd suggest creating `Date` objects and comparing them

Comment: can you show an example of the data? i can understand sorting a column on a table, but it looks like you have a multiple columns and multiple rows of dates. what sort of output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Precursors:**

I'm going to comment on your code first, just so we all know what's happening. The actual sorting happens in the call:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
  return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
});
```

The `sort()` function takes as an argument a comparator function; this is a function that takes two arguments, `a` and `b`, and returns `0` if they are equal, a negative number if `a<b`, and a positive number if `b>a`.

To sort types with strange or non-standard comparisons, you just need to rewrite your comparator!

---

**Answer:**

Therefore, you probably want to replace the above section with something like the following (note that this assumes your date column cells have an extra `date` html attribute, to distinguish them from arbitrary strings):

```
if(rows[0].cells[col].hasAttribute('date')) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var regex = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;

    //strip out the days (1), months (2), and years (3)
    var matchA = regex.exec(a[col]);
    var matchB = regex.exec(b[col]);

    //build strings of the form yyyymmdd
    matchA = matchA[3]+matchA[2]+matchA[1];
    matchB = matchB[3]+matchB[2]+matchB[1];

    return (matchA == matchB) ? 0 : ((matchA > matchB) ? asc : -1*asc);
  });
} else {
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
  });
}
```

Comment: or just compare yyyymmdd , that would simplify a lot of code : (''+matchA[3]+matchA[2]+matchA[1]>''+matchB[3]+matchB[2]+matchB[1])